# Add and Compare Datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime, compare, addition

How do I write this pseudocode in Python? With 'created_date' being a datetime object.

```
if (created_date + 30days) < now:
  print 'valid'
else:
  print 'expired'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import datetime as DT
if (created_date + DT.timedelta(days=30)) < DT.datetime.now():
    print('valid')
else:
    print('expired')
```